# Determinant of complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A1 and A2 real matrices, A = A1+iA2 and A*=A1-iA2.

If det(A) = a + ib, how can I prove that det(A*)=a-ib?

Answer (score 1):

Take the formula for the [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) and conjugate everything.